# CSS styles are not showing on multiple pages. How to resolve this in Wordpress?

Tags: wordpress

[Pages look like on the picture.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/hz2YU.png)

Answer (score 0):

Though you did not provide the problem details, it looks like the CSS did not load properly.

Check your enqueue files. And don't forget to add the `wp_head()` function before the end of the head tag in the **header.php** file and `wp_footer()` before the end of the body tag in the **footer.php** file.